# Microsoft Graph SDK documentation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using microsoft graph apis in my application along with microsoft-graph-sdk(client).
I am using sdk 1.7.1 but it doesn't contain few api like places() to get List of places.
Recently, I tried to update sdk to latest 3.2.0 and found that all my imports are failing. Almost all the classes are moved to different packages.
Here is my request, is there any documentation available for these changes?

The problem is some of the class/interface do not get imported in sdk 3.2.0 (like IEventCollectionPage, IEventDeltaCollectionPage) not sure what to replace them with as my existing implementation is failing because of this.

Below is the dependency I am trying to upgrade to:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph
compile group: 'com.microsoft.graph', name: 'microsoft-graph', version: '3.2.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/msal4j
compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'msal4j', version: '1.5.0'
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there have been quite a few releases since v1.7.1 and v.3.2.0 there might not be specific documentation to help with that migration. I would recommend going class by class and referring to the relevant graph documentation eg. [Places - Java sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#request).

For interfaces/classes that might have changed, kindly refer to the [Javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph/latest/index.html), I can see that `IEventCollectionPage` is now [EventCollectionPage](https://javadoc.io/static/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph/3.2.0/com/microsoft/graph/requests/EventCollectionPage.html) and `IEventDeltaCollectionPage` is now [EventDeltaCollectionPage](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph/latest/com/microsoft/graph/requests/EventDeltaCollectionPage.html).

Let me know if this helps, and if you've got further questions :)

Comment: Thanks @Diana , it is very helpful. Though I have couple of more queries regarding changed methods. I will try to accumulate them and post it as a separate query. Thanks